# USART format data type

Tags: type-conversion, atmega, usart

i would like to ask, how i can send data via usart as integer, i mean variable which stores number. I am able to send char variable, but terminal shows me ascii presentation of this number and i need to see number.
I edited code like shown below but it gives me error: "conflicting types for 'USART_Transmit'"

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define FOSC 8000000// Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1

void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr );
void USART_Transmit( unsigned char data );
unsigned char USART_Receive( void );

int main( void )
{
    unsigned char str[5] = "serus";
    unsigned char strLenght = 5;
    unsigned int i = 47;

    USART_Init ( MYUBRR );
    //USART_Transmit('S' );
    while(1)
    {
        /*USART_Transmit( str[i++] );
        if(i >= strLenght)
        i = 0;*/
        USART_Transmit(i);
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
    return(0);
}

void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr )
{
    /* Set baud rate */
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)ubrr;
    /* Enable receiver and transmitter */
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
    /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
    UCSR0C = (1<<USBS)|(3<<UCSZ0);
}

void USART_Transmit( unsigned int data )
{
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE)) )
    ;
    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = data;
}

unsigned char USART_Receive( void )
{
    /* Wait for data to be received */
    while ( !(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC)) )
    ;
    /* Get and return received data from buffer */
    return UDR0;
}
```

Do you have any ideas what is wrong?
PS: I hope you understand what im trying to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use `sprintf` to format numbers for serial.

At the top of your file, put:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Then write some code in a function like this:

```
char buffer[16];
sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", number);
char * p = buffer;
while (*p) { USART_Transmit(*p++); }
```

The first two lines construct a null-terminated string in the buffer.  The last two lines are a simple loop to send all the characters in the buffer.  I put a newline in the format string to make it easier to see where one number ends and the other begins.

Comment: my code is like this now: https://paste.ofcode.org/x2pAV3VaFYGJBzKyDXPyyr aaaand it works! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Technically a UART serial connection is just a stream of bits divided into symbols of a certain length. It's perfectly possible send the data in raw form, but this comes with a number of issues the must be addressed:

- How to identify the start and end of a transmission unambiguously?
- How to deal with endianess on either side of the connection?
- How to serialize and deserialize the data in a robust way?
- How to deal with transmission errors?

At the end of the day it turns out, that you never can resolve all the ambiguties and binary data somehow must be escaped or otherwise encoded to prevent misinterpretation.

As far as delimiting transmissions is concerned, that has been addressed by the creators of the ASCII standard through the set of nonprintable control characters: Of interest for you should be the special control characters

- `STX` / `0x02` / Start of Text
- `ETX` / `0x03` / End of Text

There are also other control characters which form a pretty complete set to make up data structures; you don't need JSON or XML for this. However ASCII itself does support the transmission of arbitrary binary data. However the standard staple for this task for a long time has been and is `base64` encoding. Use that for transmission of arbitrary binary data.

Numbers you probably should not transmit in binary at all; just push digits around; if you're using octal or hexadecimal digits parsing into integers is super simple (boils down to a bunch of bit masking and shifting).